# rxjs: observable with single value after delay

Tags: javascript, rxjs

My purpose is start new Observable (for e.g. Observable.of) after some delay. 
I need an initial one with single value and emitting it after time. It can be explained as:

```
<ObservableWithSingleValueAndDelay>.switchMap(val => Observable.of(1,2,3));
```

The `timer` method emits values every specified duration and `single` hasn't possibility to delay its start. So how can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: `timer` emits only once if passed a single parameter - the delay.

Comment: @cartant, yep, I'm inattentive :-/